# Query with join and in clause only returning values inside the in clause

Tags: sql, spring, jpa

I've got a table called items and it is joined with a table called tags.  I'd like to be able to search for any items that contain a list of specified tags.  What I have is working but it will only return tags listed in the query, even if the item has more associated tags.  I'd like to get the item back with all associated tags if it has the set of tags I'm searching for

```
  @Query("select d from DataItem d left join fetch d.tags t where t in (:tags)" )
  Set<DataItem> findDistinctByTags(@Param("tags") Set<Tag> tags);
```

If I have an item with tags foo and bar and search for items with a tag of foo, I'll get back a correct item but it will only come back with the tag of foo.  I'd like to get the bar tag back with the query as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following statement:

`@Query("select d from DataItem d left join fetch d.tags t where d.tags in (:tags)" )`

A good approach would also be turning on `SQL` logging for your spring application, for example, using `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and examine generated query. It is going to help you with troubleshooting.

Comment: This results in an error during runtime, "malformed numeric constant: ."